# Using Method Group gives me The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:

Tags: linq, delegates, method-group

I want to call a simple method group in Linq but I receive this error.

`The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select<string,int>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>, System.Func<string,int>)' and 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select<string,int>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>, System.Func<string,int,int>)'`

```
var num = new [] { "12345", "5432" };

num.Select(Convert.ToInt32);
```

I understand that there is ambiguity between which method to call. My question is however, is there a way of specifying the signature **without** calling the method normally. I want to save typing by not having to use lambda expressions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could cast explicitly:

`num.Select((Func<String, Int32>)Convert.ToInt32);`

Comment: Then if the answer satisfies your question you could mark my answer.